# Selected value from DropDownList always gives default value back also when something else is selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdown, selectedvalue

I'm working with ASP.NET. I have a Dropdownlist which is build dynamically. Now when you click on a submit button I try to do something only when you've selected something from the Dropdownlist (with 'if value isnot 0'). But somehow my value always gives 0 (the default value) back, also when something is selected and the value should be 1 or 2.

Anyone here who knows what might be the problem?

Here I'm looping over all my Dropdownlist and with every dropdownlist there comes an emailinput (those 2 belong together)

```
            For i As Integer = 0 To allDropDownLists.Count - 1
                If allDropDownLists(i).SelectedValue = "0" Then
                Else
                    If allEmailInputs(i).Text IsNot "" Then
                        final &= saveEventUser(myID, allDropDownLists(i).SelectedValue, allEmailInputs(i).Text)
                    Else
                        error.InnerHtml = "error!!"
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

And this is how everything gets build dynamically:

```
            Dim div71 As New Panel
            div71.CssClass = "border"
            Dim ddl As New DropDownList
            ddl.ID = "select" & panel & "_" & counter
            ddl.Items.Clear()
            ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select something", "0"))
            ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select 1", "1"))
            ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select 2", "2"))
            ddl.CssClass = "form_txt2 colegas"
```

Comment: You cannot generate a 'runat="server"' control, because they are usually pre-processed to be incorporated in the .designer.vb file

Comment: Okay, I deleted it, I just put it there because online I read that that might've been the problem but it clearly wasn't

Comment: Where is that for loop running at? Can you please provide the definition or type for the following: 'allDropDownLists()', 'allEmailInputs()', 'final', and 'saveEventUser()'.

Answer (score 0):

Create you dropdown list in the standard ASP.NET way with visibile="false", then when you populate it set its visibility to true.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" visible="false" CssClass="form_txt2 colegas"></asp:DropDownList>

ddl.Items.Clear()
ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select something", "0"))
ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select 1", "1"))
ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select 2", "2"))
ddl.Visible = true
```

Otherwise you could build a GridView in which you have a DropDownList for each row, so you can control how many rows (hence -> DropDownLists) to display - if you bind this GridView to a dataset with 5 records, you will have 5 DropDownLists.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1"  SortExpression="Column1"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" SortExpression="Column2" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You will populate these DropDownLists on the GridView RowDataBound event

Comment: That's not an option. It has to be dynamically build because there it also choses how many Dropdowns it must show. Because those dropdowns will be shown under event and the maker of the event can choose how many dropdowns there need to be. Because in the end the dropdownlists will be used to subscribe you on events.